# Homepage custom link

Tags: home-page-component

How can I add a link to the sidebar component that opens a VF page in a new page?
I have created a custom page component and a custom link like apex/myPageName but it does not work.

Comment: I guess it should be /apex/pagename .Please recheck your URL link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating your Link you can pick the Visualforce page source like so...

[image]

Then assign the Link to a component...

[image]

And finally to the layout...

[image]

My page shows in the sidebar like so and popups up in a new window...

[image]

Like so...

[image]

My page source is this, note I've removed the sidebar and header...

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page shown via the Sidebar
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is there any way to have multiple options under "My Sidebar Pages", which in turn do different things when clicked based on the contents of your VF page? Or do I have to create a separate VF page for each link?

Answer (score 2):

Specify your full URL (eg https://na1.salesforce.com/apex/pagename) for the link.

It's nice to put that prefix in a custom setting so it'll work in sandboxes, after a move, etc.

And as always, verify permissions on the page.

Comment: It's even nicer to specify the prefix without the hardcoded instance ;) Relative url like "/apex/pagename" ;)

Comment: Agreed with eyescream